# How to get next string start with info from an arraylist in the list of lines java?

Tags: java, for-loop, parsing, arraylist, split

working on a movie project but ran into some trouble.

If the file have many lines that look something like this:

Title: Avatar

Director: James Cameron

How do I make the method work?

The code is not running right now.

I created a helper method to find startswith what string first, so if the user puts in Title: or Director:, the method would return the name of either the tile or director. But java is saying that the i is not working here, it is strange, it said i can not be resolved to a variable. Also I realized if I do this, it would not work since the user is inputting a string but the line would contain both the info for title: name. How should I go about to make it work?

```
    /**
     * Lines in the file.
     */
    private List<String> lines;

    //helper method
    String getNextStringStartsWith(String str) {
        
        String[] lineArray;
        
        //iterate over list of lines
        for(i = 0; i < this.lines.size(); i++) {
            //if the specific line has that string
            if(this.lines.get(i).equals(str)) {
                lineArray = this.lines.get(i).split(":");
                info = lineArray[1].trim());
                //gets the line afterwards
                return info;
            }
        }
    }

     //Have to iterate over each line and look for lines starting with "Title:" and "Director:"
     // Set the value of this.title and this.director 
     private void setTitleAndDirector() {

        this.title = getNextStringStartsWith("Title:");
        this.director = getNextStringStartsWith("Director:");

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the for loop is that you didn't tell Java which type your variable i is. Therefore Java couldn't create a variable for it.

There were also some other small things wrong with your code.

- You were missing a return value when nothing was returned from your loop.
- You didn't tell Java which type the variable info is.
- You had a ) too much on the line on the line with lineArray[1].trim().

Here is a way you can fix these things.

```
//helper method
    String getNextStringStartsWith(String str) {

        String[] lineArray;

        //iterate over list of lines
        for(int i = 0; i < this.lines.size(); i++) {
            //if the specific line has that string
            if(this.lines.get(i).equals(str)) {
                lineArray = this.lines.get(i).split(":");
                String info = lineArray[1].trim();
                //gets the line afterwards
                return info;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question, can I change equals to contains since the line would have Title: Avatar but user would only put in Title: and the program is suppose to search for the former.

Comment: @XYZMath I am not sure i fully understood your question. But if you are asking if you can change the equals to contains, then the answer is yes you can. if(this.lines.get(i).contains(str)) {

Comment: like right now if the file has a line Title: Avatar, using the method above, it would not work because Title: Avatar is not equal to Title:, only if I change it to contains, it would be able to match the condition and retrieve the name for me?

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct. equals() will check if both Strings are 100% the same, while contains() will only check if a String can be found in a (bigger) String. For example the String "XYZMath" contains "XYZ".